# Presionar todas las teclas del teclado [C#]

Tags: c#

Me gustaría saber como poder simular el presionar de todas las teclas del teclado sin ninguna excepción.

Lo he intentado con un foreach con Keys de System.Windows.From pero nada.

Comment: a que te refires "sin ninguna excepción" ? que seria eso del "Keys", podrias poner el codigo que intentaste ?

Comment: A lo que me refiero es que falte ninguna tecla por pulsar y Keys viene de System.Windows.From y se le puede llamar así: SendKeys.SendWait(Keys.C).

Comment: porque usas el SendWait() y no simplemente el Send() ?

Comment: Porque luego tengo otra aplicación que graba cuando presionas una tecla y si lo hago con Send no lo graba bien.